# Proper way to manage watermark in flink with event scattered in time

Tags: apache-flink, flink-streaming, watermark

I'm processing a stream of events coming from IOT devices.

These events have a first level of timestamp, set by the network. They're also packing together several measures taken at different points in time. For instance:

- network time 9:08
- measure M1 taken at 8:52
- measure M2 taken at 9:07

The measures are to be aggregated hourly, in this case M1 should go in an 8:00-9:00 window, and M2 in a 9:00-10:00 window.

I wonder what is the proper way to design my flink app, manage those timestamps, and the related watermarks. From my understanding so far:

- I should probably put all the processing related to network time (9:08) in a separate Flink app.
- Have a Flink app processing the measures after they are unpacked (flap-mapped). Then assign the timestamp with `assignTimestampsAndWatermarks()`, correct ? What strategy should I use, given the 15mn spread there is between measures coming simultaneously ?

--

PS: nope, I can't change the IOT device

PPS: I plan to use EMR, so flink 1.11, if it has any impact on design.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Typically, with an out-of-order event stream, you want to use the bounded-of-order watermark strategy with a duration large enough to cover the expected out-of-orderness. So at least 15 minutes, in this case.

If you are aggregating hourly windows, this should be pretty workable -- assuming you can tolerate waiting until 15 minutes after the hour ends to see any results. If you can do incremental aggregation of the window results (via `reduce` or `aggregate`) that will be much more efficient.

Comment: thanks. For the part based on network time, the out-of-orderness is lower. Can I have a specific watermark strategy for that part, or should I separate in 2 pipelines, with only one watermark strategy for each ?

Comment: I'm not sure you actually need watermarks in the first part of your pipeline (see https://stackoverflow.com/q/67196076/2000823). But if you do, it is possible to reapply `assignTimestampsAndWatermarks` later in the pipeline.