# Does my Flink application need watermarks? If not, do I need WatermarkStrategy.noWatermarks?

Tags: apache-flink, flink-streaming

I'm not sure if my Flink application actually requires Watermarks. When are they necessary?

And if I don't need them, what is the purpose of `WatermarkStrategy.noWatermarks()`?

Answer (score 10):

A Watermark for time *t* marks a location in a data stream and asserts that the stream, at that point, is now complete up through time *t*.

The only purpose watermarks serve is to trigger the firing of event-time-based timers.

Event-time-based timers are directly exposed by the `KeyedProcessFunction` API, and are also used internally by

- event-time Windows
- the CEP (pattern-matching) library, which uses Watermarks to sort the incoming stream(s) if you specify you want to do event-time based processing
- Flink SQL, again only when doing event-time-based processing: e.g., ORDER BY, versioned table joins, windows, MATCH_RECOGNIZE, etc.

Common cases where you don't need watermarks include applications that only rely on processing time, or when doing batch processing. Or when processing data that has timestamps, but never relying on event-time timers (e.g., simple event-by-event processing).

Flink's new source interface, introduced by FLIP-27, does require a `WatermarkStrategy`:

```java
env.fromSource(source, watermarkStrategy, sourceName);
```

In cases where you don't actually need watermarks, you can use `WatermarkStrategy.noWatermarks()` in this interface.

Comment: David Anderson: If I am using event time and tumbling windows but specifiy `WatermarkStrategy.noWatermarks()` in that case will the windows close and progress? Or do I have to use processing time if I want to avoid using watermarks?

Comment: @AsimJalis Streaming jobs that use event time windows rely on watermarks to close those windows, otherwise, the windows will never close. In batch mode, the windows will close at the end of the job, even without watermarks.